# Not able to call S3 class function in r

Tags: r, functional-programming

I made a classset function that return list of variables with its class being set. Call to it is doing intended work but when call to its associated function is made, call entered into default function..

```
classset <- function(stud= TRUE, res = pass) 
{
  entry = list(student = stud, result= res)
  class(entry) <- "registration"
  return(entry)
}

setrecord <- function(rec,newval)
{
  print("in setting")
  UseMethod("setrecord",rec)
}
setrecord.default <- function(m,n)
{
  print("in def")
  return(m)
}

setrecord.classset <- function(m,n){
  print("in class func")
  m$stud  <- aqqi
  m$res <- n
  return(m)
}

reh <- classset("aqqi","pass")
reh$student

[1] "aqqi"

reh$result

[1] "pass"

reh <- setrecord(reh,"fail") ##Expecting call to setrecord.classet

[1] "in setting"
[1] "in def"                   # expected to print "in class func"   

class(reh)
[1] "registration"
```

I was actually expecting call to class specific function setrecord.classset. 
 appreciate if anyone could point what  i am missing in this.

Comment: Please supply a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue is that you have not named your class `classset`, but `registration`, as seen here:

```
classset <- function(stud= TRUE, res = pass) 
{
  entry = list(student = stud, result= res)
  class(entry) <- "registration" ### XXX: This is the name of the class
  return(entry)
}
```

So, we need to create an S3 method for the `registration` class:

```
setrecord.registration <- function(m,n){
    print("in class func")
    m$stud  <- "aqqi" # Note I also had to add the quotation marks here
    m$res <- n
    return(m)
}
reh <- classset("aqqi","pass")
reh$student
# [1] "aqqi"
reh$result
# [1] "pass"
reh <- setrecord(reh,"fail") # Will call setrecord.registration()
# [1] "in setting"
# [1] "in class func"
reh
# $student
# [1] "aqqi"
# 
# $result
# [1] "pass"
# 
# $stud
# [1] "aqqi"
# 
# $res
# [1] "fail"
# 
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "registration"
```

Comment: Oh!! I see.. Thanks.